# DB configuration for library in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am using Spring Boot for creating Microservices. I have implemented a common library (jar) where other Microservices uses it for security and validation purposes. I have a requirement to have on common functionality where it requires DB connection.

I have planned to use the same common library to implement, but to supply the DB details, each Microservice using this common library has to configure the DB details in its corresponding `application.properties`. I wanted to know is this right approach of asking individual microservice to supply DB details in a agreed property names and it can be used by library ?

Another option I think is to implement it as a another Microservice and other Microservices can invoke using RestTemplate. But I don't want to do this as it is a simple functionality.

Comment: Can this shared jar *just* expect presnce of a DataSource bean in classpath ? Each of the service can then go on to create its instance of DataSource the way it pleases ?

Comment: I am also looking for same kind of solution. But, seems like nobody have implemented in such a way where we can create a library for db connection.